# A characterization for finitely presented modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $M$ be a module over $R$. We say that $M$ is finitely presented if there exists an exact sequence $$R^{m}\longrightarrow R^{n}\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow0$$ for some nonnegative integers $m$ and $n$.

In the book I am reading, it states that $M$ is finitely presented if and only if  $M$ is finitely generated and for every surjective $R$-linear map $\psi:N\rightarrow M$, where $N$ is finitely generated, the kernel $\text{ker}\psi$ is finitely generated.

I know that the $M$ being finitely presented implies the other statement (using the snake lemma), but I don't know how to prove the converse. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Loosely speaking, your first definition says, that a module is finitely presented if there is one choice of finitely many generators, that has only finitely many relations between them.

Your second definition says that a module is finitely presented if any choice of finitely many generators has only finitely many relations beetween them.

So you are actually asking for the trivial direction of the equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the latter condition holds. Since $M$ is finitely generated, there is an $R$-linear surjection $R^n\to M\to 0$ for some $n$. Now, the kernel is finitely generated so you can get a similar exact sequence for $K=\ker(R^n\to M)$ and, "concatenating" these two sequences, you can produce an exact sequence of the desired form $R^m\to R^n\to M\to0$.